# C# - Monitor incoming data to an IoT Hub *without* Stream Analyzer

Tags: c#, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I've been working on a proof-of-concept meter-to-cloud messaging system, and, at this point, have a very short time-frame available to me. I've gotten a good portion of it done already: my IoT device is currently successfully sending data up to it. The next step would be to pull the data in real-time and visualize it in a C# Winforms application.

The problem is that I am currently unable/unwilling to pay for Stream Analytics - the standard way of routing the data to either a Service Bus / or an Azure Function Application. Is there another way of doing it that avoids SA?

I've had a few ideas. One: I wondered if maybe their REST API would allow me to pull the data from the server. But it seems they haven't provided a call for that. Another, much more promising lead: Microsoft also provides a Device Explorer that monitors the incoming data from the IoT device:

> (https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer)

That monitoring functionality does exactly what I need to do. The problem is that there are hundreds on hundreds of files in the source code, and I keep getting lost sifting through it.

Anyone ever done something like this before? If so: you have any ideas?

Note: I'd like to reiterate the fact that I'm looking for a **free** option.

Answer (score 1):

I have done that using Azure Time Series Insights ( it does provide a REST API) .Though not real time but near real time (atleast 10 seconds delay).Have documented entire steps here :
http://learniotwithzain.com/2019/03/near-real-time-iot-data-exploration-using-azure-time-series-insights/

Hopefully this would help you with your requirements.

Comment: Time Series Insights comes out to $29.436 per unit per month. I'm avoiding Stream Analytics because there is money involved. Do you really not know a free option?